# AngularJS is not working when render through layout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a sample application with AngularJS and ASP.Net MVC. I got a problem while adding references of angular. If I add reference through layout file application stops working and through error in console

```
>     ReferenceError: angular is not defined
>     var reportApp = angular.module('reportApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

But if i add angular reference directly in the page it works fine.

Comment: Double check your network tab and see if there is a 404 entry in there or if the browser is requesting angular.js from the server or not.

Comment: I am referencing angularJS from local folder. There is no 404 issue angularJS is loading from properly in network tab from both(layout and from page) but it didn't works if it have reference from layout page

Comment: can you post html of your page? did you referenced layout in your page?

Comment: here is my script and console panel when I add reference through layout page: http://screencast.com/t/Smog57H594r
http://screencast.com/t/EJU8Bgftzvs

If I add reference from page 
http://screencast.com/t/n5zXl888jA

Comment: There is a clear warning message that you are doing something wrong. It says that you are trying to load angular more than once. You probably referenced the file twice.

Comment: Yes, actually it is loaded from layout and page also but if i comment out reference from page it stops working.
http://screencast.com/t/EJU8Bgftzvs